# Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory using handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi I am very new to web development in Node JS. At work today I was tasked to setup an environment for a web application. I am using handlebars, but I am having trouble making 'view engine setup' to work in order to render the 'views' files and the layouts folder. I have looked at the documentation and every stack overflow post that is similar to my issue, but I still get nowhere. Here is my code below for server.js and the architecture of my app. I will really appreciate any feedback thanks in advance!

```
 var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var handlebars = require('handlebars');
    var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
    var app = express();
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    //view engine setup
    app.set('views', './views')
    app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs' }));
    app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    //routes
    app.get('/home', function(req, res){
    res.render('home');
    });
    //error handlers
    //404 catch-all handler(middleware)
    app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.status(404);
    res.send('404');
   });
    //500 error handler(middleware)
    app.use(function(req, res, err, next){
      console.error(err.stack);
      res.status(500);
      res.send('500');
   });
   // development error handler
   // will print stacktrace
   if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
     app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
       res.status(err.status || 500);
       res.render('error', {
         message: err.message,
         error: err
       });
     });
   }
   // production error handler
   // no stacktraces leaked to user
   app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
     res.status(err.status || 500);
     res.render('error', {
       message: err.message,
       error: {}
     });
   });

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
console.log('Listening on port 5000');


fgcms
├── server.js
├── node_modules
└── package.json
├── public
└── views
       ├── layouts──home.hbs
       └──main.hbs
```

Comment: Your home.hbs is inside layouts and your views are set to ./views directory so you have probably to put this on render res.render('layouts/home')

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo I tried that already and it didn't work, I understand it should be a problem when I set my views to the view folder, I just don't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If home.hbs is is not layout then what is it doing in layout folder????
Also main.hbs is probably layout and you don't have it in layout folder. So first place hbs files to correct folders. Now if home.hbs is in views folder *./views/home.hbs* then res.render('home'); should work

Comment: @Molda that did not work either mate :(

Comment: I just noticed that it complains about error view. So do you have *./views/error.hbs*?

Comment: @molda my mistake, forgot to edit my comment Molda you the correct response to my issue. Thank you!

Comment: @Molda , you should provide an answer so that hjm can select it as the answer - this would make SO more clear for future visitors (and you get the points ;)